# Wait for all promises to resolve

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

So I have a situation where I have multiple promise chains of an unknown length. I want some action to run when all the CHAINS have been processed. Is that even possible? Here is an example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    var one = $q.defer();
    var two = $q.defer();
    var three = $q.defer();

    var all = $q.all([one.promise, two.promise, three.promise]);
    all.then(allSuccess);

    function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data + "Chained";
    }

    function allSuccess(){
        console.log("ALL PROMISES RESOLVED")
    }

    one.promise.then(success).then(success);
    two.promise.then(success);
    three.promise.then(success).then(success).then(success);

    $timeout(function () {
        one.resolve("one done");
    }, Math.random() * 1000);

    $timeout(function () {
        two.resolve("two done");
    }, Math.random() * 1000);

    $timeout(function () {
        three.resolve("three done");
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
});
```

In this example, I set up a `$q.all()` for promises one, two, and three which will get resolved at some random time. I then add promises onto the ends of one and three. I want the `all` to resolve when all the chains have been resolved. Here is the output when I run this code:

```
one done 
one doneChained
two done
three done
ALL PROMISES RESOLVED
three doneChained
three doneChainedChained
```

Is there a way to wait for the chains to resolve?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

> I want the all to resolve when all the chains have been resolved.

Sure, then just pass the promise of each chain into the `all()` instead of the initial promises:

```
$q.all([one.promise, two.promise, three.promise]).then(function() {
    console.log("ALL INITIAL PROMISES RESOLVED");
});

var onechain   = one.promise.then(success).then(success),
    twochain   = two.promise.then(success),
    threechain = three.promise.then(success).then(success).then(success);

$q.all([onechain, twochain, threechain]).then(function() {
    console.log("ALL PROMISES RESOLVED");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my worst fear. Now I have to come up with a way to get the last promise lol.

Comment: What's the problem with that? Are your chains dynamically constructed?

Comment: Exactly my problem. I am trying to dynamically create a promise chain then I want to do something when the chain(s) complete.

Comment: Can you show us your code (maybe ask a new question)? Are there items appended to the chain after `Q.all` was executed - otherwise it should be trivial?

Comment: I would love to show you the code... but I haven't finished writing it yet, however I will do my best to explain it. I have a list of "actions" that need to be done. These actions may have any number levels of sub-actions associated with them. I want to be able to do something when all the actions and their subactions are complete. There will likely be multiple `$q.all`s, however once I start the resolution process, no new actions/promises will be chained.

Comment: Yeah, you'd recursively descend the tree of actions with multiple `all()` calls for subactions on each level - then you only need to call `act(rootAction).then(…)`

Comment: Exactly, I just haven't gotten that far yet or figured out how to build the `all()` correctly for each level.

Comment: s/each level/each node/ - sorry if that has caused some confusion.

Answer (score 16):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761711/1653521) is correct. I would like to provide an example to elaborate it a bit to those who aren't familiar with `promise`.

**Example:**

In my example, I need to replace the `src` attributes of `img` tags with different mirror urls if available before rendering the content.

```
var img_tags = content.querySelectorAll('img');

function checkMirrorAvailability(url) {

    // blah blah 

    return promise;
}

function changeSrc(success, y, response) {
    if (success === true) {
        img_tags[y].setAttribute('src', response.mirror_url);
    } 
    else {
        console.log('No mirrors for: ' + img_tags[y].getAttribute('src'));
    }
}

var promise_array = [];

for (var y = 0; y < img_tags.length; y++) {
    var img_src = img_tags[y].getAttribute('src');

    promise_array.push(
        checkMirrorAvailability(img_src)
        .then(

            // a callback function only accept ONE argument. 
            // Here, we use  `.bind` to pass additional arguments to the
            // callback function (changeSrc).

            // successCallback
            changeSrc.bind(null, true, y),
            // errorCallback
            changeSrc.bind(null, false, y)
        )
    );
}

$q.all(promise_array)
.then(
    function() {
        console.log('all promises have returned with either success or failure!');
        render(content);
    }
    // We don't need an errorCallback function here, because above we handled
    // all errors.
);
```

**Explanation:**

From AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

The `then` method:

> **then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)** – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls
>   one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the
>   result is available. The callbacks are called with a **single
>   argument**: the result or rejection reason.

$q.all(promises)

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when
>   all of the input promises are resolved.

The `promises` param can be an array of promises.

About `bind()`, More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: The `then` method of `$q.all` is provided an array of the returned promises, so you can loop that array and call `then` on each item in the array, as opposed to calling `then` when you add the promise to `promise_array`.

Answer (score 4):

Recently had this problem but with unkown number of promises.Solved using [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

```
function methodThatChainsPromises(args) {

    //var args = [
    //    'myArg1',
    //    'myArg2',
    //    'myArg3',
    //];

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var chain = args.map(methodThatTakeArgAndReturnsPromise);

    $q.all(chain)
    .then(function () {
        $log.debug('All promises have been resolved.');
        deferred.resolve();
    })
    .catch(function () {
        $log.debug('One or more promises failed.');
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: It's not jQuery.map() but Array.prototype.map() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but this approach works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. `$q.all(...`

You can check the below stuffs:

http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasBurleson/QqKuk/

http://denisonluz.com/blog/index.php/2013/10/06/angularjs-returning-multiple-promises-at-once-with-q-all/

Comment: That requires me to know the length of my chain though right? I mean if I had a promise of length 10, I would have to do `$q.all([p1.then(..).then(...).then(...).then(...) ...]);` right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["await" in an "async function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', async function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  ...
  var all = await $q.all([one.promise, two.promise, three.promise]); 
  ...
}
```

NOTE: I'm not 100% sure you can call an async function from a non-async function and have the right results.

That said this wouldn't ever be used on a website. But for load-testing/integration test...maybe.

Example code:

```js
async function waitForIt(printMe) {
  console.log(printMe);
  console.log("..."+await req());
  console.log("Legendary!")
}

function req() {
  
  var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("DARY!");
    }, 2000);
    
  });

    return promise;
}

waitForIt("Legen-Wait For It");
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this example used in the [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs) library:

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(paths, function loading(path) {
    promises.push(buildElement('css', path, params));
});
$q.all(promises).then(function success() {
    callback();
 }, function error(err) {
        callback(err);
  });
```