# AngularJS: Cannot Retrieve JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am currently creating a Dynamic Dropdown based on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfEMw/4/)

I followed through except I tried to call a JSON file instead. My code looks like this:

```
scope.metro = [{"branch": "SM North EDSA"}, {"branch": "Trinoma"}, {"branch": "Xanland Katipunan"}, {"branch": "Farmers Market"}, {"branch": "Alimall"}, {"branch": "SSX Caloocan"}, {"branch": "Victory Mall"}, {"branch": "SM Valenzuela"}, {"branch": "City Square Malabon"}, {"branch": "SM Novaliches"}, {"branch": "SM Fairview"}, {"branch": "Zabarte Mall"}, {"branch": "SM Megamall"}, {"branch": "EDSA Shangrila"}, {"branch": "Robinsons Galleria"}, {"branch": "Greenhills"}, {"branch": "R. Pioneer"}, {"branch": "SM Taytay"}, {"branch": "SM Masinag"}, {"branch": "SM Marikina"}, {"branch": "Rob Metro East"}, {"branch": "SSX Marikina"}, {"branch": "Burke Plaza"}, {"branch": "Binondo"}, {"branch": "Rob Ermita"}, {"branch": "SM Marikina"}, {"branch": "SM San Lazaro"}, {"branch": "SM Centerpoint"}, {"branch": "SM MOA"}, {"branch": "SM Bicutan"}, {"branch": "SM Sucat"}, {"branch": "Rob Magnolia"}, {"branch": "SM Paranaque"}, {"branch": "Coloc Palawan"}, {"branch": "Cash & Carry"}, {"branch": "Greenbelt 1"}, {"branch": "Waltermart Makati"}, {"branch": "Ministop Cattleya"}, {"branch": "Market Market"}, {"branch": "Festival Mall"}, {"branch": "SM Muntinlupa"}, {"branch": "SM Southmall"}, {"branch": "SM Las Pinas"}, {"branch": "Commonwealth"}];
scope.central = http.get('central.json');
scope.north = http.get('north.json');
scope.south = http.get('south.json');
scope.visayas = http.get('visayas.json');
scope.mindanao = http.get('mindanao.json');

scope.region = [
{ type: 'Metro Manila', data:scope.metro, displayName:'branch' },
{ type: 'Central Luzon', data:scope.central, displayName:'branch'},
{ type: 'North Luzon', data:scope.north, displayName:'branch'},
{ type: 'South Luzon', data:scope.south, displayName:'branch' },
{ type: 'Visayas', data:scope.visayas, displayName:'branch'},
{ type: 'Mindanao', data:scope.mindanao, displayName:'branch'}
```

];

scope.metro works, but the rest won't when connected to a JSON file. I was assuming it would work since it's practically the same structure. What am I doing wrong here?

[EDIT]

I tried this http injection initially before what I did above as answered by some of you:

```
http.get('mindanao.json').success(function(data){
  scope.mindanao = data;
})
```

This did not work that's why I tried the other way. So I was assuming it has something to do with the JSON assignment.

Comment: `http.get` returns a promise, not the data itself

Comment: its not clear from  the js fiddle but you also need to inject ```$http``` into wherever you are making the call from. ie. the controller or factory

Answer (score 2):

Because `http.get` returns a promise, and not the data itself, this won't work. You have to add the data in the success function:

```
$http.get('central.json').success(function (data) {
    scope.central = data;
});
```

Mind that when adding the `scope.central` to the `scope.region` will not work here, because it might not be available yet. Better would be to wait for all promises to be resolved, and then add the data to the `scope.region` object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759361/wait-for-all-promises-to-resolve) can be found how to do that.

Comment: This was the initial approach I did. It still did not work, hence I resorted to the one I wrote above.

Comment: How do I make all of its promises resolve before adding to `scope.region`?