# How to call function after API gets are finished inside of for loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, promise, angular-promise

Below is a for loop which will run a max of time times, Inside of that for loop I make a GET call to return some data that needs to be added to my `obj` object.

I need some way to tell when all 3 `GETS` are finished as well as the `for loop` before calling the `TagFactory.buildSavedView(obj)` line. Thoughts?

```
for (var i = 0; i < termIDs.length; i++) {
    ApiFactory.getTagData(tickers[i], termIDs[i]).then(function(data) {
        singleTagArray.push(data.data.tickers);

        var updatedTag   = TagFactory.renderDirections(singleTagArray, null, period);
            newTagObject = updatedTag[0];

        tags.push(newTagObject);

        finishObjSetup(tags);
        console.log('viewHeaderDirect > obj: ', obj);
    });
}

TagFactory.buildSavedView(obj);
vm.loadSavedModal = false;
```

Comment: jQuery [deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: @CoolBlue why jQuery deferred when angular has `$q`..for more details look at mine answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait for all promises to resolve](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21759361/1048572)

Comment: @PankajParkar got another promise question for you if you have time :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328924/how-to-use-the-q-promise-feature-in-this-situation-to-wait-for-data-to-be-ready

Comment: @LeonGaban sure I m looking at it

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks! yeah this is kinda different, since the API call is in a different Service and not the Controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `$q.all`, but creating a promise array and pass it to `$q.all` that will execute its `.then` only when all the promises gets executed.

**Code**

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < termIDs.length; i++) {
    var promise = ApiFactory.getTagData(tickers[i], termIDs[i]).then(function(data) {
        singleTagArray.push(data.data.tickers);

        var updatedTag   = TagFactory.renderDirections(singleTagArray, null, period);
            newTagObject = updatedTag[0];

        tags.push(newTagObject);

        finishObjSetup(tags);
        console.log('viewHeaderDirect > obj: ', obj);
    });
    promise.push(promise); //creating promise array.
}

$q.all(promise).then(function(){
    //here the call will goes after all calls completed.
})
```

Comment: @LeonGaban actually its 2 min.. I saw this question late :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple counter:

```
var y = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < termIDs.length; i++) {
  ApiFactory.getTagData(tickers[i], termIDs[i]).then(function (data) {
    y++;
    singleTagArray.push(data.data.tickers);

    var updatedTag = TagFactory.renderDirections(singleTagArray, null, period);
    newTagObject = updatedTag[0];

    tags.push(newTagObject);

    finishObjSetup(tags);
    console.log('viewHeaderDirect > obj: ', obj);

    if (y === termIDs.length) {
      TagFactory.buildSavedView(obj);
      vm.loadSavedModal = false;
    }

  });
}
```