# AngularJS : How to use the $q promise feature in this situation to wait for data to be ready?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I have a **Controller** which starts an API call in a **Factory**. Currently I start the call, then I have a function after that call to check the status of the `Array`. However I'm not sure how to force it to wait here while the data is being gathered, thus the need for some kind of `$q` implementation.

As you can see in the screenshot below, `vs.tickers` returns an empty Object, or Array. Then finally the `console.log` in GetTickersFactory fires:

[image]

**1st Controller**

```
if (root.tickerType === 'portfolio') {

    // Call to factory to start the API GETS:
    GetTickersFactory.getTickers('portfolio');

    // I then call a function in the Factory to return the array
    // Which isn't ready yet of course since it returns undefined...
    vs.tickers = GetTickersFactory.returnPortfolioTickers();

    console.log('portfolio');
    console.log('vs.tickers = ', vs.tickers);
}
```

**getTickers function in the GetTickersFactory** | 
Perhaps this helps: [the Gist for the full Factory](https://gist.github.com/leongaban/b28041b258e010815e6e).

```
function getTickers(type, load, searchedTicker) {
    load = load || loadString; searchedTicker = searchedTicker || '';

    var portfolioTickersArray = [], searchedTickersArray  = [];

    tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = false;

    switch(type) {
        case 'searched':
            ....
            break;

        case 'portfolio':

            if (portfolioCached) {
                // The API Call (cached)
                ApiFactory.getWatchList().then(function(data) {
                    portfolioTickersArray = renderTickers(data.data.tickers, undefined, type);
                    portfolioTickers.that = portfolioTickersArray;
                    tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = true;
                    console.log('portfolioTickersArray: ', portfolioTickersArray);
                    return portfolioTickersArray;
                });

            } else {
                // The API Call (not cached)
                ApiFactory.getWatchListRefresh().then(function(data) {
                    portfolioTickersArray = renderTickers(data.data.tickers, undefined, type);
                    portfolioTickers.that = portfolioTickersArray;
                    portfolioCached = true;
                    tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = true;
                    console.log('portfolioTickersArray: ', portfolioTickersArray);
                    return portfolioTickersArray;
                });
            }
            break;
    }

    function renderTickers(data, searchedTicker, type) {
        ....
    }
}
```

**The return Array function I'm using inside of the getTickersFactory.js I believe I shouldn't use this however and figure out how to use promises instead:**

```
function returnPortfolioTickers() {
    return portfolioTickers.that;
}
```

---

Note I did originally try this, but with the same results:

```
vs.tickers = GetTickersFactory.getTickers('portfolio');
```

`vs.tickers` would return `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch cases should return a promise so that it caller function will `.then` called when promise gets resolved

**Factory Code**

```
function getTickers(type, load, searchedTicker) {
    //other code remains same
    tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = false;
    switch (type) {
        case 'searched':
            return ApiFactory.getTickers(null, load).then(function(data) {
                //other code remains same
                if (tickersPane.tempTickers.length > 0) {
                    //other code remains same
                    return returnData(searchedTickersArray);
                }
                return []; //return default variable to continue promise chain
            });
            break;
        case 'portfolio':
            tickersPane.addOption = false;
            tickersPane.removeOption = true;
            tickersPane.displayTopTags = false;
            tickersPane.displayPortfolio = true;

            if (portfolioCached) {
                return ApiFactory.getWatchList().then(function(data) {
                    //other code remains same
                    return returnData(portfolioTickersArray);
                });
            } else {
                return ApiFactory.getWatchListRefresh().then(function(data) {
                    //other code remains same
                    return returnData(portfolioTickersArray);
                });
            }
            break;
    }
    function renderTickers(data, searchedTicker, type) {
        //this should be as is
    }
    function returnData(data) {
        tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = true;
        return data;
    }
    //tickersPane.loadingTickersDone = true;
    //return data; //removed this line and move to function
}
```

**Controller**

```
if (root.tickerType === 'portfolio') {
    // Call to factory to start the API GETS:
    GetTickersFactory.getTickers('portfolio').then(resp){
         vs.tickers = GetTickersFactory.returnPortfolioTickers();
         console.log('portfolio');
         console.log('vs.tickers = ', vs.tickers);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `then.(function(resp` to fix a bug... now `vs.tickers` is just `[]` the first time still... but the 2nd time it does update with data... but for some reason my model in the view did not update, debugging more

Comment: Ah everything was working, I had a variable I needed to pass to change an `ng-hide` status :)

Comment: Question, why do you have 2 returns here: `return returnData(searchedTickers.that);
                        return []; //return default variable to continue promise chain` I actually updated that code a bit, removed the `if else` statement, and return the array. What's the purpose of `return []` ?

Comment: @LeonGaban I added that because method should return it `tickersPane.tempTickers.length` less than zero..otherwise the `.then` function will not get fired..It is not needed if you removed if else..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the ES6-styled promise:

```js
function getTickers(type, load, searchedTicker) {

  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

     if (doTheGoodThings()) {
       resolve('This is ok!');
     } else {
       reject('This did not work');
     }

  }
}
```

And then in your controller:

```js
if (root.tickerType === 'portfolio') {

  GetTickersFactory.getTickers('portfolio').then(function (result) {
    console.log('Worked: ' + result);
  }, function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have two methods that return promises (getWatchList and getWatchListRefresh) so you can just return those methods and chain more `.then`s. No need to use $q here.

Hopefully this simplified example might help steer you in the right direction...

```
function getTickers(type) {
    var tickers;

    switch(type) {
        // ...
        case 'portfolio': 
            var getList = portfolioCached ? getWatchList : getWatchListRefresh;
            // tickers will be set to the promise returned
            // by getWatchList or getWatchListRefresh
            tickers = getList().then(function(data) {
                if (!portfolioCached) {
                  portfolioCached = true;
                }
                // the result returned by renderTickers will be 
                // passed to any `.then` that is chained
                return renderTickers(data.data.tickers, undefined, type);
            });
        break;
    }

    // return the tickers promise
    return tickers;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
// the `tickers` param here will be the result
// returned by renderTickers()
GetTickersFactory.getTickers('portfolio').then(function(tickers) {
    vs.tickers = tickers;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` but still working on it.

Comment: You need to ensure all of your switch cases assign a promise to `tickers`. Have you done that?

Comment: I've created a much more simplified version of this to show it working: http://jsbin.com/deqijubipi/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks @jjenzz, +1 I like that you used a ternary function here :) will try this out in another area of my app.