# How can I compare the values between this two functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to compare the `variable` values of this two functions. Unfortunately I have tried to make the `variables` `global` but I keep getting `undefined`.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name dashyAppApp.controller:Dashy3Ctrl
 * @description
 * # Dashy3Ctrl
 * Controller of the dashyAppApp
 */

angular.module('dashyAppApp')
  .controller('Dashy3Ctrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, employees, $interval) {
   var _this = this;

  $scope.getData = function() { // getDATA function
    employees.getEmployees().then(function(response){
        _this.items = response.data;
        $scope.items = _this.items;

       callmecrazy(response.data);
    });

  }// End getDATA function
  $scope.getData();

  $scope.getDataB = function() {
  employees.getEmployees().then(function(response){
    _this.items = response.data;
     callmecrazier(response.data);
  });
 }
 $interval(function(){
 $scope.getDataB();
 }, 10000);

 function callmecrazier(response1){
   callmecrazierVal = response1.countries;
    return callmecrazierVal;
 }

 function callmecrazy(response){
  callmecrazyVal = response.countries;
  return callmecrazyVal;
 }

 if(!angular.equals(callmecrazierVal(), callmecrazyVal())) {
    //trigger some other function
  }
});
```

I want to check if `callmecrazierVal !== callmecrazyVal`. That is my complete `controller` code above.

```
if(callmecrazierVal !== callmecrazyVal){
  //trigger some other function
}
```

Comment: `var` makes them local, if you want them global remove it. You could also use `return` instead of console log, then compare the function calls.

Comment: Where do those responses come from?

Comment: @Bergi I will edit the code to see where they come from!

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj: I guessed something like that :-) Have a look at [how to wait for multiple promises](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21759361/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values returned by the functions are not primitives you should:

```
if(!angular.equals(callmecrazier(), callmecrazy()) {
   //trigger some other function
}
```

**EDIT**
I am assuming you want to hit api at interval of 10secs and check if there are any changes, right? (else, please clarify what you are trying to achieve). If so you need to chain the async calls and then compare like below:

```
'use strict';

 /**
  * @ngdoc function
  * @name dashyAppApp.controller:Dashy3Ctrl
  * @description
  * # Dashy3Ctrl
  * Controller of the dashyAppApp
 */

angular.module('dashyAppApp')
 .controller('Dashy3Ctrl', function($rootScope, $scope, employees, $interval)            {
 var _this = this;

 $scope.getData = function() { // getDATA function
     return employees.getEmployees().then(function(response) {
       return response.data; 
     });

   } // End getDATA function


$scope.getData()
.then(function(data1){
   $scope.items = data1; 
   $interval(function() {
     $scope.getData()
     .then(function(data2){
        if (!angular.equals($scope.items, data1) {
          //trigger some other function
        }
     });
   }, 10000);

});

 });
```

Comment: angular.js:13920 ReferenceError: callmecrazierVal is not defined

Comment: see edit. you should ofcourse compare the return values of the 2 functions.

Comment: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of undefined
    at callmecrazier

Comment: yes I want to hit the API check for changes , if there are changes , then update my template view. I tried your above function but it doesn't work  to update the view unless after a refresh!

Answer (score 2):

You should return something from your functions. The returned value will them be compared.

```
function callmecrazier(response1){
   var callmecrazierVal = response1.countries;
    return callmecrazierVal;
 }

 function callmecrazy(response){
  var callmecrazyVal = response.countries;
  return callmecrazyVal;
 }
```

Then compare them like this:

```
if(callmecrazierVal() !== callmecrazyVal()){
  //trigger some other function
}
```

Comment: it says callmecrazierVal is not defined.

Comment: 1. Make sure that you're calling this function from the same scope.
2. Do not forget parenthesis `()` while calling this function.

Comment: I added more code so u see where am getting the response .

Comment: where is the `if` condition in your code? If you're using `if(callmecrazierVal !== callmecrazyVal){` then you have forgotten parenthesis. Use `if(callmecrazierVal()  !== callmecrazyVal() ){` instead

Comment: you are assuming values returned are primitives.

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj **(1)** you've written your `if` condition directly in your controller. How will it get executed? You should write it in some function block and then you should call that function. **(2)** both of your functions i.e., `callmecrazier` and `callmecrazy` expects some parameter. Where are you passing those parameters when you're calling those functions from `if` condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
function callmecrazier(response1){
   var callmecrazierVal = response1.countries;
   return callmecrazierVal;
}

function callmecrazy(response){
   var callmecrazyVal = response.countries;
   return callmecrazyVal;
}

if(callmecrazier(response1) !== callmecrazy(response)){
   //Your code...........
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: response1 is not defined. I will edit the code to add how I am getting the response values.

Comment: Pass value in function. I think response1 is your element.